# Полная копия объекта

Tags: c#, .net

Ситуация: Есть дженерик класс. В одном из своих методов он в качестве параметра принимает объект класса  которым инициализирован дженерик и сохраняет во внутренней коллекции.

Нужно сохранить во внутренней коллекции полную копию переданного в параметрах объекта. (эдакое сохранение текущего состояния объекта)

Вопрос: Как создать полную копию экземпляра неизвестного на этапе компиляции класса?

Comment: [`ICloneable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @VladD если мне на этапе компиляции не известен класс объекта как я могу узнать, что он реализует ICloneable? И что если не реализует? К тому же нет гарантии что Clone создаст полную(глубокую) копию...

Comment: можно с использование рекурсии и рефлексии, можно добавив ограничение на generic параметр [ICloneable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.icloneable(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Alexey, всего предусмотреть невозможно

Comment: @Grundy Некоторые из тех объектов, что передаются в класс не реализуют ICloneable. Выходит единственный "универсальный" вариант это использовать рефлексию и рекурсивный обход "внутрянки" объекта?

Comment: Плюс писать страшные велосипеды для обхода циклических ссылок и умудриться не уйти вверх по дереву до уровня всего приложения.

Comment: @Alexey, вполне возможно, объединить классы которыми специфицируется основной generic класс общим интерфейсом, в данном случае `ICloneable` и объекты тогда _должны_ будут его реализовывать, ведь логично, что никто не сделает копию объекта лучше чем он сам :-)

Comment: @Grundy некоторые из специфицирующих классов это UIelement'ы, объединить их с пользовательскими классами одним интерфейсом не выйдет...

Comment: А как вы себе представляете копию UIElementa вообще? Скорее всего, вы делаете что то не так. В каком нибудь DDD копии можно делать исключительно у агрегатов (сущности и дочерние сущности), у остальных копия не имеет смысла и ценности.

Comment: @Monk я пока ещё не сделал ничего "не так", только, так сказать, собирался... Копию  UIElementa в частности я себе как полностью идентичный по свойствам и дочерним объектам элемент. Есть какие-то проблемы сделать глубокую копию UIElement'а о которых мне неизвестно?

Comment: Именно WPF контролы лучше уж тогда как то так - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f9e7b2fb-8142-438a-835e-a6d31c2dde4a/copy-uielement?forum=wpf а в целом - копирование должно иметь какой то смысл. Может вы уточните, что у вас за класс и зачем ему копия?

Comment: @Monk: Смысл-сохранение текущего состояния объекта, возможность получить одно из предыдущих состояний объекта и историю изменений. Хотел универсальный дженерик который смог бы обрабатывать любые типы объектов, но, по ходу придётся специализировать класс под конкретные объекты и задачу.

Comment: @Monk: Сереализация/десереализация UI Объектов XMLReader/Writer'ом неплохой вариант, при условии, что ресурсы копируемого объекта заданы статически. Если скажем взять картинку которой в рантайме нарисовали изображение и присвоили в качестве сорса то то XMLReader выдаст ошибку при попытке собрать объект из строки полученой XMLWriter'ом

Comment: Нужно ли вам хранить изменения где то при выключении приложения или достаточно истории изменений в памяти? В любом случае, контролы напрямую хранить не стоит, хранить стоит их DataContext, который в принципе может быть ограничен уже вами созданными вьюмоделями со строго определенными интерфейсами.

Comment: UI-элементы? А зачем вам их копии? А как вы собираетесь копировать event'ы? А attached properties? Забудьте, вы идёте по неправильной дороге. Какая ваша _настоящая_ задача?

Comment: @Monk таки да, достаточно истории изменений в памяти и да, в модели описаны классы которые можно использовать для сохранения состояния. Этот путь более долгий чем тот, который мне грезился возможным при существовании возможности сделать полную копию "сферического объекта в вакууме"

Comment: История изменений тоже может быть разной... если вам нужно undo\redo - это одно, если нужен rollback на явно сохранённое состояние - другое. На вашем месте, я бы подумал над тем, что же вы пытаетесь сделать и оформил бы новый вопрос =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Отталкиваясь от обсуждения в комментариях: вы решаете вашу задачу неправильнымн путём. Для реализации функциональности undo/redo, которую вы на самом деле хотите сделать таким вот образом, не нужно клонировать объекты, тем более — UI-объекты.

Для начала, почему есть проблема с UI-объектами. Для произвольного объекта вы не знаете, что есть реальное свойство этого объекта (то есть, принадлежащий ему подобъект), а что лишь ссылка на чужой объект. Вследствие этого вам придётся клонировать все свойства. Например, `Parent`, `Tag` и `DataContext`.

Далее, свойства объекта могут храниться в неожиданных местах. Например, attached properties хранятся в месте, не доступном для рефлексии, имея лишь экземпляр объекта, и не зная более ничего.

Поскольку через `Parent`/`Children` доступен корневой элемент, а затем и все элементы, вы вынуждены будете клонировать всё окно. Поскольку через `DataContext` доступна VM, то заодно вам придётся прохватить и её. А поскольку в VM есть ссылки на модель, то вы, таким образом, заберёте с собой **вообще всё приложение**. Включая, кстати, поле, в котором хранится история изменений.

Затем, есть набор объектов, которые принципиально не клонируются. Открытый файл? Сокет? Залоченный `Monitor` (он же `lock`)? Брошенное исключение? Любой синглтон из вашей программы? `Type`? Делегат? Все они не склонируются.

---

Что же реально *нужно*? Нужно представлять состояние программы или её частей при помощи VM- и модельных объектов. Если вы хотите сохранять их, имеет смысл сделать эти объекты иммутабельными, чтобы бы не было риска, что их состояние изменится после того, как вы сохранили копию. (Разберитесь с immutable-объектами, их легко писать так, чтобы при изменении куски объекта-источника повторно использовались. Если все куски неизменяемые, их можно использовать где угодно без необходимости клонирования точно так же.)

Далее, ваш View обязан строго следовать паттерну MVVM, и отображать состояние VM, без отсебятины и установки важных штук в code behind. При этом состояние вашего View будет полностью определяться состоянием VM, а значит, необходимость в запоминании View отпадёт.

При этом единственные объекты, которые вам придётся запоминать (не клонировать, а именно запоминать!) — текущее состояние.

Comment: Ну, вопрос скорее был теоретическим. Из серии возможно/невозможно. Хотя да,причина определена верно- undo/redo с примочками.У меня в VM уже реализован функционал сохранения/загрузки файлов соотв. реализовать undo\redo не проблема . Просто изначально функционал  undo/redo не был предусмотрен. Это уже правки так сказать... вот в процессе обдумывания изменений и дополнений которые нужно будет внести в код и созрел этот вопрос, созрел потому, что представилось, что было бы здорово один раз реализовать undo/redo класс-дженерик который потом можно повторно использовать в других проектах

Comment: @Alexey: Ну, теоретически склонировать _произвольный_ объект не получится. Если уж `ICloneable` не подходит (то есть, не все объекты умеют/хотят склонировать себя сами так, как вам нужно), то уж склонировать неизвестный заранее объект и подавно невозможно.

Answer (score 2):

Есть несколько способов. Самый верный — это сериализовать класс и скопировать байты. Но не самый быстрый, к сожалению.
Делается это примерно так:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

/// <summary>
/// Reference Article http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/SerializedObjectCloner.aspx
/// Provides a method for performing a deep copy of an object.
/// Binary Serialization is used to perform the copy.
/// </summary>
public static class ObjectCopier
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Perform a deep Copy of the object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of object being copied.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="source">The object instance to copy.</param>
    /// <returns>The copied object.</returns>
    public static T Clone<T>(T source)
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsSerializable)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The type must be serializable.", "source");
        }

        // Don't serialize a null object, simply return the default for that object
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(source, null))
        {
            return default(T);
        }

        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
        using (stream)
        {
            formatter.Serialize(stream, source);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

Ограничение в том, что класс должен быть сериализуемым. 
Без требования сериализации придется вручную копировать и следить за тем, что бы объект и его сериалиующая функция находились в соотвествии.

Comment: Хороший вариант, мне как-то в голову не пришёл, хотя буквально недавно использовал сериализацию. Но, к сожалению "мои" объекты не сериализуются...

Comment: Тогда интерфейсы. Т.е. не просто genetic,а Savior<T> where T:IStateContent, и потом по интерфейсу выцеплять поля и работать с ними...

Comment: @Alexey используйте суррогаты сериализации (ISurrogateSelector)

Comment: Можно попробовать еще через рефлекшн. Но если попадется циклическая ссылка — то stackoverflow обеспечен.

Comment: @user3345929 а что за IStateContent? не смог нагуглить такой интерфейс...

Comment: Сорри за дезинформацию, я имел ввиду некий свой интерфейс, описывающий контракт состояния объектов, который ты знаешь еще на этапе компиляции. Т.е. сохраняешь состояние ты не некого object, а объекта, у которого ты знаешь точно, есть поля {...} вот такие.

Comment: Кстати, суррогаты сериализации тут могли бы подойти. Т.е. делегировать сериализацию иному объекту.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте следующий код:

```
public sealed class CopyHelper
{
    private static readonly Type array_type = typeof(Array);

    private static readonly MethodInfo memberwise_clone = typeof(object)
        .GetMethod("MemberwiseClone", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    private static void MakeArrayRowDeepCopy(Dictionary<object, object> state,
        Array array, int[] indices, int rank)
    {
        int next_rank = rank + 1;
        int upper_bound = array.GetUpperBound(rank);

        while (indices[rank] <= upper_bound)
        {
            object value = array.GetValue(indices);
            if (!ReferenceEquals(value, null))
                array.SetValue(CreateDeepCopyInternal(state, value), indices);

            if (next_rank < array.Rank)
                MakeArrayRowDeepCopy(state, array, indices, next_rank);

            indices[rank] += 1;
        }
        indices[rank] = array.GetLowerBound(rank);
    }

    private static Array CreateArrayDeepCopy(Dictionary<object, object> state, Array array)
    {
        Array result = (Array)array.Clone();
        int[] indices = new int[result.Rank];
        for (int rank = 0; rank < indices.Length; ++rank)
            indices[rank] = result.GetLowerBound(rank);
        MakeArrayRowDeepCopy(state, result, indices, 0);
        return result;
    }

    private static object CreateDeepCopyInternal(Dictionary<object, object> state,
        object o)
    {
        object exist_object;
        if (state.TryGetValue(o, out exist_object))
            return exist_object;

        if (o is Array)
        {
            object array_copy = CreateArrayDeepCopy(state, (Array)o);
            state[o] = array_copy;
            return array_copy;
        }
        else if (o is string)
        {
            object string_copy = string.Copy((string)o);
            state[o] = string_copy;
            return string_copy;
        }
        else
        {
            Type o_type = o.GetType();
            if (o_type.IsPrimitive)
                return o;
            object copy = memberwise_clone.Invoke(o, null);
            state[o] = copy;
            foreach (FieldInfo f in o_type.GetFields(
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public))
            {
                object original = f.GetValue(o);
                if (!ReferenceEquals(original, null))
                    f.SetValue(copy, CreateDeepCopyInternal(state, original));
            }
            return copy;
        }
    }

    public static T CreateDeepCopy<T>(T o)
    {
        object input = o;
        if (ReferenceEquals(o, null))
            return o;
        return (T)CreateDeepCopyInternal(new Dictionary<object, object>(), input);
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
SomeClass copy = CopyHelper.CreateDeepCopy(original);
```

Код копирует любые объекты. Корректно обрабатывает циклические ссылки. Работает достаточно быстро за счёт использования `MemberwiseClone`.

Код взят [отсюда](http://forum.codenet.ru/q28188) (смотрите внизу предпоследнее сообщение, автор hardcase).

PS: если кто-то потестирует код, отпишитесь о результатах.

Comment: Совсем любые, включая Remoting Proxy? :)

Comment: @PashaPash - ну, такие тяжёлые случаи в рассчёт не берём. И, вообще, мопед не мой...