# Клонирование коллекций ICollection<Element>

Tags: c#

Необходимо клонировать коллекцию так, чтобы все её объекты Element так же отвязались от исходной коллекции. Подскажите, как лучше всего это сделать?

Comment: что значит `отвязались от исходной коллекции`? Приведите ваш код

Comment: Вам нужно _глубокое копирование_ - deep copy? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/537280/184217

Comment: @tym32167, это значит, что при осуществлении различных операций (например, добавление элементов) над клонированной коллекцией, оригинал коллекции остался неизменным

Comment: ну так создайте новую коллекцию и положите туда элементы из старой, какие проблемы?

Comment: @tym32167, через метод Add() в конструкции foreach? Если да, то не срабатывает: при удалении объектов в оригинале, почему-то удаляются данные в копии

Comment: `var copy = new List<MyType>(originalCollection);`